# JSON Track return wrong datas

Tags: json, api, deezer

I queried few month ago (and cached result!) the search API for artist "les baxter" and get this track :

`{"id":"61363484","readable":true,"title":"santa claus party","link":"http:\/\/www.deezer.com\/track\/61363484","duration":"129","    rank":"5525","preview":"http:\/\/cdn-preview-5.deezer.com\/stream\/5072868e9e053dee0622fc373350ca7b-0.mp3","artist":{"id":"437026","name":"les baxter & his orchestra","link":"http:\/\/www.deezer    .com\/artist\/437026","picture":"http:\/\/api.deezer.com\/2.0\/artist\/437026\/image"},"album":{"id":"6012510","title":"louis armstrong sings \"what a wonderful christmas\"","cover":"http:\/\/ap    i.deezer.com\/2.0\/album\/6012510\/image"},"type":"track"}`

but when i try today to reach the track link, i get a 404 - not found - error. Can you help me guys ? Did you change your ids ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID has not changed but the rights about this song yes, that's why you cannot get informations about.

Comment: Thx for your answer. The error code 800 => DATA_NOT_FOUND is not really clear on what is going on with the api call. Maybe a more explicit error code could be helpful for all devs.